# Having problem with Select append() in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

All the code works will. When I put console.log(value.rental_id), all the rental_id pop out in the console, meaning I suspect the problem is in the append code, but I have tried a lot of methods, till can't fix it.

The json data is coming out too, working fine

Appreciate your help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "rental_id_json.php";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
      console.log(value.rental_id);
      $('#rental_id').append('<option value="' + value.rental_id + '">' + value.rental_id + '</option>');

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<select type="text" name="rental_id" id="rental_id" class="input">
  <option value="-" selected>Rental ID</option>
</select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezf1N.png)

Comment: In `<select>` what is `type="text"`?? .. Please check your HTML .. Also Nothing wrong with the `append` part in your code .. You may have a duplicated id somewhere .. To check that use `$('select[name="rental_id"][id^="rental_id"]').append(.......`

Comment: I check that with my original code, it appears in the inspect elements console but it doesn't display in my interface.
I have checked too, there is no duplicate id, it is the only ID out of my whole database script

Comment: I don't know @Adam but the `append` looks fine to me ..But if you use any `select` plugin you should refresh the plugin after the `append`